# Color converting in java

Tags: java

I am wanting to get rgb value of each pixel in an image. For this I used `getRGB()` which returns an integer that I converted with `Color(arg,true)`. If I print out the `getRGB()` results and paste one of the numbers into the `Color` class it works. But if make an integer as shown equal rgb and put it in `Color` so I can cycle through each pixel it returns 255 for all values.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.*;

public class kmeans {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("andy.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(i, j);
                // System.out.println(rgb);
                Color c = new Color(rgb, true);
                // System.out.println(c.getRed()+" "+c.getGreen()+" "+c.getBlue()+" ");
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are *so many* pixels; perhaps that really is the result (many of them) for each of the many white pixels in the image?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: A lot of them are white but not all based on the integers returned by getRGB(). But running it through Color makes them all 255.

Comment: insert an if statement and only print out non-white pixels to see if any exist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `new Color(rgb, true)` to `new Color(rgb, false)`? When you get the int value for rgb, you don't get the alpha value (aka the transparency of the current pixel). When using that value in the constructor, without having an alpha value, it could mess with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine and the problem, assuming there is one, is elsewhere. Here is a sample of the output your code produced for some random JPEG:

```
java.awt.Color[r=126,g=116,b=104]
java.awt.Color[r=122,g=112,b=100]
java.awt.Color[r=116,g=106,b=94]
java.awt.Color[r=117,g=107,b=95]
java.awt.Color[r=123,g=113,b=101]
java.awt.Color[r=122,g=112,b=100]
```